# Light Transmission Through Half-Hollow Sphere

Tags: lightning

I am looking for a light source, preferably a laser, for a specific optical experiment. The experiment involves a spherical object positioned 6 meters away from this light source. My goal is to shine the laser through the sphere, specifically aiming for the light to enter the larger hole and exit the smaller hole on the opposite side. The sphere itself is 2 meters in diameter (given its 1-meter radius) and it has two distinct holes on opposite sides: one hole has a diameter of 1 meter, while the other hole is significantly smaller with a diameter of 5 centimeters. I intend to conduct this experiment in a foggy environment or during the night, as this will enhance the visibility of the light beam. My ultimate objective is to ensure that the light exiting the 5-centimeter hole travels in a straight line, thus creating a beam effect in the surrounding environment.

Any suggestions on the appropriate lighting setup for this light transmission will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have a problem getting a laser beam wide enough to fill a 1 m hole. A searchlight may be your best bet.

If your object is a hollow shell and you can put lenses inside, you could theoretically do this with a telescope. Shine the light into the big end of a telescope and have it come out the small end. Again, it will be hard to find a telescope with a big end $1$ m across, and the small end $5$ cm across.

You will have better luck if you scale the project down to a smaller size.

Comment: It would be a sphere made out of stainless steel, without any other contents inside. I was thinking of combining the usage of both laser and a searchlight.